# 500 ma for 100 ma requirement?

Tags: power-supply

I have an RF repeater (for an alarm system) that requires a 12VDC 100 ma power source. If I use a transformer/power supply that rated at  12VDC 500 ma, will I do any harm to the RF repeater or the power supply?  From high school electronics class, I think I remember that this should be OK -- but I just wanted to check.

Answer (score 1):

The power supply is rated at 12Vdc and can supply up to 500mA. This means it will not be overloaded with a 100mA load. That's the theory anyway but i will add that it is totally worth measuring the 12VDC output with a meter first to

a) Make sure you know the polarity i.e. which line is positive and

b) Ensure it doesn't produce 18V on light loads dropping down to 12V on full load.

Don't be surprised at (b) - I've seen it

Comment: Just to clarify b), it must be a regulated power supply. Regulated means the output will be 12V (or close to it) without much variation for differences in current.